# For connecting to Mysql with my netcore api should i use a json file to connect or should i use code below

Tags: c#, mysql, api, asp.net-core-mvc

```
using (var Connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    Connection.Open();
    using (var Command = new MySqlCommand(Command, Connection))
    {
        using (var executeReader = Command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (executeReader.Read())
            {
                ValuesList.Add(new BloodBankPro
                {
                    key_id = executeReader.GetInt32(0),
                    FirstName = executeReader.GetString(1),
                    lastName = executeReader.GetString(2),
                    BloodType = executeReader.GetString(3),
                    age = executeReader.GetInt32(4),
                    Gender = executeReader.GetString(5)
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For this, I connect it every time but should I use a JSON file to define the connection string and should I define a command, etc

Answer (score 0):

You must keep such configuration settings in appsettings.json file.
[App Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if you want to use ADO.NET to connect to the mysql database, I suggest you could put the connection string into appsettings.json file instead of write it in codes.

The advantage of this is if you want to modify the connection string, you could just change the connection string value in the appsettings.json.

Then if you want to get the connection string, you could inject the IConfiguration into your class and then use  `Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")` to get the details connections string.

More details, you could refer to below sample:

Appsettings.json example:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-IdentityTestDemo-32EC7F23-BFDD-4025-8D9C-2394643F484B;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Use dependency injection to get the connection string in controller or else:

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
          
            _logger = logger;
            _configuration = configuration;

        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {

            var re = _configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            return View();
        }
}
```

Result:

[image]